# How to modally present a ViewController from SceneDelegate?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uiwindow, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have an `OnboardingViewController` which available to access from app's settings in a modal style.

When a user opens the app first time I want to show him the `OnboardingVC` in the same modal style (with an upper tabs effect, like so: [Screenshot](https://cln.sh/ZDZTrW)) as it loads if to present it from the Settings.

`SceneDelegate` setup:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OnboardingViewController") as! OnboardingViewController
    window?.rootViewController = controller
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
 }
```

The problem it's always appear in a full screen, without the above modal tabs effect at the top.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't present a `UIViewController` (modally or fullscreen) which is window's `rootViewController`.

To show Onboarding screen when user open app for the first time, set Home Screen/Login Screen (or any screen you want) as `rootViewController` in `SceneDelegate`. Then from that `UIViewController` you can check if user open app for first time or not. Depending on that you can show the Onboarding screen.

You must embed the `rootViewController` in a `UINavigationViewController` to present/push another `UIViewController`

In **SceneDelegate.swift** modify the code like below.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
    //embed in UINavigationController
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
    window?.rootViewController = navController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
 }
```

Then in the Home screen (i assume it as HomeViewController) check the status of first opening and present Onboarding screen.

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OnboardingViewController") as! OnboardingViewController
        controller.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        self.present(controller, animated: true)
    }
}
```

You can get the `rootViewController` from anywhere in the app by using the code below. And then present any ViewController you want to show.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OnboardingViewController") as! OnboardingViewController
        controller.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController
rootVC?.present(controller, animated: true)
```

Comment: Hi, MBT! Thank you for such a detailed answer! Accept your solution, it's perfect. Would you be so kind to tell me your opinion: what if I'll make a segue from `HomeViewController` to `OnboardingViewController` in Storyboard and in `HomeViewController` in `viewDidAppear()` just call the `performSegue()`? Will it be an alternative or that approach has disadvantages?

Comment: Glad to know that it helps. Your proposed approach is totally fine. There is no disadvantage. Thanks.